# How to take input value from outside form action without javascript?

Tags: php

I still in training,
But i stuck in this problem.

```
// we need this password in 2 form POST
<input style='text' name='password' />

<form action='delete.php' method='POST'>
  ... // i need password to be here
  <input type='submit' name='delete' value='Del' />
</form>

<form action='edit.php' method='POST'>
  ... // and i need password to be here too
  <input type='submit' name='edit' value='Edit' />
</form>
```

My menthor want to do this using 2 form but I need the input password outside this 2 form.
Are there any way to do this without using script?
I can do this with 1 form and `action.php` that include 2 php file(`edit.php` and `delete.php`)
But he said that it is waste.
Can someone help? I already checking using search engine and found nothing.

Comment: I know about hidden but I want user to input password and click delete or edit button. And than the password will be go to the the PHP file using POST method. But the input password is outside the form. And without javascript.

What i can do to get this value of password that is outside the form action?

Comment: yup exactly. You can update the hidden inputs forms using javascript. If the user type something on the outside password form.. it will update the hidden inputs on both of your forms.

Comment: Do you know the other way without using javascript? because using javascript is forbidden.

Comment: Your mentor must have hated you that much.. kidding.. No.. I dont know how. Maybe someone here knows.. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your mentor just testing you on how you solve the situation.. As far as i know... you cant pass value of a textbox upon submit without putting the textbox inside a form.. I just wonder why javascript is forbidden.. Well anyway I suggest you to use 1 form and 1 page for the action and in the action make an if statement to separate you delete and edit method.. maybe in that case it is not waste.. It's just only a suggestion..

Comment: I already use that. Maybe you're right, I already ask my mentor via email but still no answer. Maybe i'll wait and still searching for solution.